# How to search an element in arraylist?

Tags: java, search, arraylist

Example is I want to search code A25 and A29 then it will print it? I cant seems find the syntax for searching long words in arraylist.

```
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrList.add("A25            CS 212          Data Structures         3");
    arrList.add("A26            IT 312          Data Base Management System 2   3");
    arrList.add("A27            IT 312          Data Base Management System 2   3");
    arrList.add("A28            IT 212          Data Base Management System 2   3");
    arrList.add("A29            CS 313          Digital Design          3");
    arrList.add("A30            IT 212          Discrete Structures     3");
    arrList.add("A25            IT 212          Discrete Structures     3");
    arrList.add("984            Engl 3          Speech and oral Communication   3");
    arrList.add("582            Theo 3          Christ and Sacraments       3");
    arrList.add("470            Stata1          Probablility and Statistics 3");
    arrList.add("999            Dota 2          Dota Guide          3");
    System.out.println("Enter code to search");
    int code = scan.next();
    //Desired output
   Enter code to search: 
   A29
   A30

   A29          CS 313          Digital Design          3
   A30          IT 212          Discrete Structures     3
   //
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: if you want to search on basis of code then make a `Map` where key is code and value is your data

Comment: I think you need to use `Map` instead of `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` is indexed based. you can only access it through the index number not like a `key` and `value` pair. If you want to pick the value for the code `A25` or `A29` as you have mentioned then I suggest better to use a `Map`

Comment: Consider using this `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: If you can, create a POJO of data

Answer (score 6):

You better create a class and add attributes like branch,rollno..etc to that class and add object of that class to arrayList and iterate and compare to find specific attribute you are looking for.Right now it's hard to search such a big String and looks bad practice though.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
String code = scan.nextLine();
for (String s : arrList) {
  if (s.startsWith(code)) {
    System.out.println(s);
    break; //optional, depending on your use case
  }
}
```

It should output exactly what you want.

Comment: Why don't just `break;` the loop if element has been found? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrList.add("A25            CS 212          Data Structures         3");
        arrList.add("A26            IT 312          Data Base Management System 2   3");
        arrList.add("A27            IT 312          Data Base Management System 2   3");
        arrList.add("A28            IT 212          Data Base Management System 2   3");
        arrList.add("A29            CS 313          Digital Design          3");
        arrList.add("A30            IT 212          Discrete Structures     3");
        arrList.add("A25            IT 212          Discrete Structures     3");
        arrList.add("984            Engl 3          Speech and oral Communication   3");
        arrList.add("582            Theo 3          Christ and Sacraments       3");
        arrList.add("470            Stata1          Probablility and Statistics 3");
        arrList.add("999            Dota 2          Dota Guide          3"); 
     List <String> searchResult = new ArrayList<String>(); 
               for (String content : arrlist) {
                   if(content.matches("a29")){
                       searchresult.add(content);
                   }
               }
```

Comment: `if(string.matches("a29"))` what is `string` in this

Comment: @Amit,I changed string to content

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List <String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();//list of codes to search
codes.add("A25");
codes.add("A29");
List <String> result = new ArrayList<String>();//list of search results
for(String s:arrList)
    for(String code:codes)
        if (s.startsWith(code))
            result.add(s);
for(String s:result)
     System.out.println(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through all the array list for every input search code, you can create one hashmap to store key, value pair as follows :

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("A25","CS 212          Data Structures         3");
map.put("A26","IT 312          Data Base Management System 2   3");
.....
.......
```

Now, it is really easy to get the element by `code`. Use HashMap#get(key) method

```
String code = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(code + " " + map.get(code));
```

This is your desired output.

But, I would say [@Task's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26292657/1031945) is the correct one.